# Get the length of list in haskell

Tags: haskell

So I made 4 functions and "all" of them return an error on an empty array

```
--
myLength1        :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
mylength1 []     =  0
myLength1 (_:as) =  1 + myLength1 as

--
myLength2        :: [a] -> Integer
mylength2 []     =  0
myLength2 (_:as) =  1 + myLength2 as

myLength3        :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
mylength3 []     =  0
myLength3 (a:[]) =  1
myLength3 (a:as) =  1 + myLength3 as

myLength4        :: [a] -> Integer
mylength4 []     =  0
myLength4 (a:[]) =  1
myLength4 (a:as) =  1 + myLength4 as
```

ghci output

```
HCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> 
Prelude> :load myLength.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( myLength.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> myLength1 ""
*** Exception: myLength.hs:4:1-36: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLength1

*Main> myLength2 ""
*** Exception: myLength.hs:9:1-36: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLength2

*Main> myLength3 ""
*** Exception: myLength.hs:(13,1)-(14,36): Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLength3

*Main> myLength4 ""
*** Exception: myLength.hs:(18,1)-(19,36): Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLength4

*Main>
```

The exception message is not really helpfull, and the `myLength1` was actually copied from  http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching.

I hope somebody can explain to me what's wrong.

---

Thank you all for the enlightenment!!

clearly I had a typo but shouldn't the haskell compiler complain about this?

I tried

```
myLength1        :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
myLength2        :: [a] -> Integer
myLength3        :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
myLength4        :: [a] -> Integer
myLength4 []     =  0
myLength4 (a:[]) =  1
myLength4 (a:as) =  1 + myLength4 as
myLength3 []     =  0
myLength3 (a:[]) =  1
myLength2 []     =  0
myLength2 (_:as) =  1 + myLength2 as
myLength1 []     =  0
myLength1 (_:as) =  1 + myLength1 as
```

and all worked fine.. and it is incomprehensible.. I just realized now but haskell is a write anywhere kinda language.. like I don't have to keep my $#!t clean as long as it don't stink.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the letter "l" in `mylength1` should be uppercase.

Comment: `myLength1` isn't defined for empty lists; you defined a separate function `mylength1` that is *only* defined for empty lists.

Comment: oh my.... a typo... (/_~ ;)
I hope I don't get an award for this...

jokes aside.. shouldn't the haskell compiler provide an error for this or perhaps a warning?

Comment: @mika It does! "Non-exhaustive patterns in function" says that you're missing a pattern in your function, which is the case since your base case isn't being covered.

Comment: @mika Good point! This is why it's recommended to enable warnings with `-Wall`. (Arguably, that should be on by default...). You can add at the top of your file `{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}` to always keep warning enabled.

Comment: Oh my @chi! lifesaver Thank you! the `-Wall` compiler option **does not** appear on the 1st few chapters of any haskell beginner book!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rather simple, but difficult to spot issue. Let's look at myLength1 for example:

```
myLength1        :: (Num b) => [a] -> b
mylength1 []     =  0
myLength1 (_:as) =  1 + myLength1 as
```

You define your function on line 1 as myLength1. However, on line 2 you pattern match with a function called mylength1. The reason you are receiving the error "Non-exhaustive patterns in function" because line 2 is not recognized as your base case, since they are not using the same function names.

This seems to be the case for the rest of your functions.

Hope this makes sense!